# select onChange notworking

Tags: javascript, html

I have a sort function that is working when using a div and an a tag. But when change to a select option, it does not work.

```
         <select id="sort-container" onchange="sortCards()">

                <option>
                    <a href="javascript:sortCards('peoplecard', 'Services')">
                        Business 1
                    </a>
                </option>

                <option>
                    <a href="javascript:sortCards('peoplecard', 'Architect')">
                        Business 2
                    </a>
                </option>

                <option>
                    <a href="javascript:sortCards('peoplecard', 'Law')">
                        Business 3
                    </a>
                </option>
          </select>
```

Comment: You're not passing any arguments to `sortCards()` in the `onchange`

Comment: Why are you putting anchors in the `<option>`? I don't think that makes any sense.

Comment: @Barmar "How to confuse screen-readers' users 101"

Comment: Don't add any `<a>`s is in the `<option>`s, they won't have any effect. Instead, add the `value` attribute to each `<option>` and then process that value in your event listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your html structure to this:

```
<select id="sort-container">
    <option value="services">
        Business 1
    </option>
```

Get select tag value in sortCards function:

```
const val = document.getElementById('sort-container').value;
```

Comment: Thank you all it is working now. I changed it and updated my sortCards() 

 <option value='Services'>
    Business 1
  </option>

Comment: @laminsuso You are welcome. If my answer is what you need, mark as accepted answer please)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass arguments to the `sortCards()` function. You can put the second argument in the value of each option, and use `this.value` to get it.

```
<select id="sort-container" onchange="sortCards('peoplecard', this.value)">
  <option value='Services'>
    Business 1
  </option>

  <option value='Architect'>
    Business 2
  </option>

  <option value='Law'>
    Business 3
  </option>
</select>
```